# Unable to create a table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to execute this simple query.

```
create Table test1
{
 ID int identity(1,1),
 value nvarchar
}
```

Its throwing an error as

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '{'
```

I am stuck here. Please help me out of this

Answer (score 3):

Use `()` instead of `{}`

```
create Table test1
(
 ID int identity(1,1),
 value nvarchar
)
```

Answer (score 2):

don't use follow brace. you should use parenthesis.

```
create Table test1
(
 ID int identity(1,1),
 value nvarchar
)
```

Syntax for create table:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
column_name1 data_type(size),
column_name2 data_type(size),
column_name3 data_type(size),
....
);
```

Answer (score 1):

- Use parenthesis `( )`  instead of curly braces `{ }`
- Set data size for the `nvarchar`. other wise when insert any string value more than 1 character you will receive `String or binary data would be truncated.` error
- Not mandatory but adding `NOT NULL` to the `IDENTITY` column is good practice.
- Adding schema name to the table is good practice. (By default `dbo` is the schema)

So the working query will be:

```
create Table dbo.test1
(
 ID    int identity (1, 1) NOT NULL,
 value nvarchar (500)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use () instead of {} 
Check out this link for the example [SQL Create Table](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp)
On the internet about the topic you will find many useful information.